# FB Analytics Push Campaigns - "Set up Your Push Campaigns" remains after implementation

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, facebook-sdk-4.x, facebook-analytics

I'm trying to implement FB Analytics Push Campaigns.

Even after the clients' implementation is complete and running (iOS + Android), the dashboard is stuck on "Set up Your Push Campaigns" and doesn't allow me to create audiences and send pushes:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me.

You can not register devices prior to supplying correct credentials (GCM API key and APNS certs) to the Analytics Setup section.

This screen can be accessed via the small cog wheel at the bottom left corner of the dashboard.

Comment: Hi, I am experimenting with FB Push Campaign and our app is developed using phonegap. However, I can't seem to register the devices properly so they would be eligible for the push campaign. This is the plugin I used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook-push-campaign